# JavaScript : Split inconsistency

Tags: javascript, split

I had a very perplexing result using split() method with JavaScript.

```
var winning = "1234".split(" ");
var entry1 = "23".split(" ");
var entry2 = "123".split(" ");
var entry3 = "55".split(" ");
var entry4 = "8888".split(" ");
var entry5 = "21".split(" ");
var counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5;
counter1 = 3;
counter2 = 3;
counter3 = 3;
counter4 = 3;
counter5 = 3;
for(var i = entry1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(winning[counter1] + "===" + entry1[i]);
    counter1 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(winning[counter2] + "===" + entry2[i]);
    counter2 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry3.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(winning[counter3] + "===" + entry3[i]);
    counter3 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry4.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(winning[counter4] + "===" + entry4[i]);
    counter4 -= 1
}

for(var i = entry5.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(winning[counter5] + "===" + entry5[i]);
    counter5 -= 1
}
```

As I run this simple code, the winning array from using split are all undefined in any index but other arrays produced by split method seems to work fine. Just why? What kind of inconsistency is this?

Comment: No inconsistencies. Everything works correctly. Your `winning` list has only 1 item. So it is impossible to retrieve 3rd.

Comment: If you need '4===23', you change 'winning[counter4]' with 'winning[0][counter4]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```js
var winning = "1234".split(" ");
var entry1 = "23".split(" ");
var entry2 = "123".split(" ");
var entry3 = "55".split(" ");
var entry4 = "8888".split(" ");
var entry5 = "21".split(" ");

console.dir(winning)
console.dir(entry1)
console.dir(entry2)
console.dir(entry3)
console.dir(entry4)
console.dir(entry5)
```

There is only one element in the `winning` array, so when you try to get element with index `3` you get `undefined`. Other arrays also have one element - you loop through them and print that one element. I think you want to do this:

```
var winning = "1234".split("");
```

instead of this:

```
var winning = "1234".split(" ");
```

because there is no space character in those strings.